# Business Intelligence reporting with mySql

Tags: mysql

Are there any good open source projects for Business Intelligence reporting in mySql or is there a commercial option that is not too expensive? Am in a 5 man shop so spending a lot of $$$ is not an easy option

Answer (score 1):

Pentaho is a good option...
http://www.pentaho.com/

It's opensource, I have a friend that sells BI and use this solution to delivery and he likes it a lot

There is also JasperSoft but I didn't heard anything about it
http://www.jaspersoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might as well have a look to [icCube](http://www.icCube.com); there's a community edition that might be enough for your needs; otherwise the enterprise edition are quite affordable compared to the major actors of the market.

Comment: Affiliations with recommended products should be disclosed in the post. http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 1):

Then you have [InfoBright](http://www.infobright.com) which is a MySQL fork. They have their own columnar oriented storage engine which is optimized for BI/DW type of queries. Having the same SQL syntax and index free tables it could be an interesting choice for a MySQL shop. There is a crippled community version free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

There is Eclipse-plugin based, [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/intro/). We have just started using it and so far it seems good. We are using the community edition and my knowledge on other versions is limited. Otherwise, [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) is a great option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to confirm the Pentaho Choice. There's a Pentaho Business Suite that you can buy,
but you are free to get all the tools for free.

I use Pentaho Data Integration to data pump raw data from our database in France, all the way to mauritius in Africa. PDI handles the file transfer with ssh then performs the loading with all the business logic in it and finally remove files that have been loaded successfully from the production server.

I've tried a bit the reporting tool it's a very complete product.

All it takes is time and effort to learn. The community online is very active and the developers answer on the forum Directly (I know the PDI project leader does)